# Android: How selection of thumbnail replaces main image

Tags: android, image, scale, thumbnails

I have a selection of thumbnails. On selection the thumbnail image replaces the main_image.

My layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/lightGray"
tools:context=".ExpandedProduct">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/product"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                 />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnails"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

(Each thumbnail is loaded into the recycler.)
**Problem:  When I click on a thumbnail, it becomes the main image, but it is very small - smaller than the thumbnail.**
(I tried to wrap the main_image in a Constraint Layout - no change.)

To react to the click I've implemented an interface where the adapter is set.  Here the onClick code, where the thumbnail becomes the main image, within my fragment script:

```
all_image.setAdapter(new ProductImagesAdapter(getProductImages(), new ProductImagesAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(String url)
    {
        ImageRequest manRequest = new ImageRequest(url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Bitmap response)
            {
                main_image.setImageBitmap(response);
            }
        }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            Log.d("Image Request", error.toString());
        }
    });
                    NetworkVolleySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(manRequest);
    }
}));
```

As you can see I'm loading the image from it's URL using *Volley*.

**How can I get the selected thumbnail image to fill the main_image "frame"?**

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't the fault of Volley or the image layout.  I was passing a url of a tiny image.